# what is the better way to write a pattern for validating this string?

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex pattern that starts with a class name and has dot between class names and ends with a class name
each class name,starts with a letter.it is like class import in java,

I wrote this pattern but it is too complex and slow for validating and I think it does not work properly

```
^([a-zA-Z]([0-9]|_|[a-zA-Z])*)(([a-zA-Z]([0-9]|_|[a-zA-Z])*)|\\.)*([a-zA-Z]([0-9]|_|[a-zA-Z])*)$
```

for example my input string should be like this: "com.casp.common.StringUtils"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, simplification:

```
[0-9]|_|[a-zA-Z]
```

can be combined as

```
[0-9_a-zA-Z]
```

and actually it has a shorthand representation

```
\w
```

so your regex can first be simplified to this equivalent form:

```
^([a-zA-Z](\w)*)(([a-zA-Z](\w)*)|\.)*([a-zA-Z](\w)*)$
```

Now, we could further simplify by removing some redundant capture groups, and **turn on case-insensitive matching**:

```
^[a-z]\w*([a-z]\w*|\.)*[a-z]\w*$
```

Of course this regex is incorrect, it matches `a....b`, for instance.

The problem is because the `\.` is an "alternative", which should not be, as a dot is *required* between each component. So it should probably transformed to:

```
^[a-z]\w*([a-z]\w*\.)*[a-z]\w*$
```

but it is still incorrect because it won't match `a.b`, because of the leading part. We need to remove it:

```
^([a-z]\w*\.)*[a-z]\w*$
```

and probably rearrange it such that the repeating part is at the end, not the start:

```
^[a-z]\w*(\.[a-z]\w*)*$
```

Comment: thanks Kenny, ^([a-zA-Z](\w)*)(([a-zA-Z](\w)*)|\.)*([a-zA-Z](\w)*)$
it matches a.b, and did not match a.b.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with just the following:

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.?)+$
```

It will match the class names with any number of packages inside of it as long as there is one. If you need at least two instances the following will work fine as well:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.?){1,}$
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it matches the com.casp.common.StringUtils. 
it ends with a dot

Comment: Ah that it does, and as a cue it is too late.